# Changing default font size in Org LaTeX export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, pdf

Org exports LaTeX with default font size of 11 pts. Is it possible to make this font size to 10 pts and also reduce spacing to one and half space ?
Regards

Comment: The general question of changing font size is more complex, as a given document class may or may not support the desired font size. Consider the extsizes package if you bump into this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you can do this with:

```
#+latex_class_options: [10pt]
```

and

```
#+latex_header: \usepackage{setspace}
#+latex_header: \onehalfspacing
```

Comment: hi John! love your stuff, I always end up at your website when googling how to do things with elfeed

Comment: Thanks for this answer. When I try `#+latex_header: \documentclass[12pt]{article}` this does not have any effect, The document is printed with 11pt font. But when I added your suggestion `#+latex_class_options: [12pt]` this worked. Do you know why `#+latex_header: \documentclass[12pt]{article}` does not change the font size?

Comment: the latex class is set by #+latex_class, not by a latex_header. those lines all go after the class definition. See https://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-header-and-sectioning.html